# How to run simple HTML & CSS project in WebStorm? (404 localhost)

Tags: html, css, node.js, webstorm

I'm trying to run simple UX project.

I have HTML and CSS files, but I don't know, how to run it with WebStorm. I've tried to click on Chrome icon, but 404
[image]

Please, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on index.html page in webstorm and choose run from menu or press ctrl+shift+f10

also you can run page directly from browser address bar:

```
file:///D:/Frontend/01-about-cats/index.html
```

[image]

Comment: open chrome and enter this address file:///D:/Frontend/01-about-cats/index.html  in address bar for direct access